# I cannot put this CustomValidator to validate two TextBoxes at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I had two RegularExpressionValidators that were being used for one textbox each. They were basically validating if the TextBox had only numbers. If, they had non-numbers input, they would throw their error.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionMontanteMin" runat="server"
            ErrorMessage="O campo 'Total com Imposto' deve ser numérico." ControlToValidate="tbMontanteMin"
            CssClass="error errorImage" Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="^[+-]?[0-9]{1,11}(?:\,[0-9]{1,2})?$"
            ValidationGroup="PesquisarFaturas">
            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionMontanteMax" runat="server"
            ErrorMessage="O campo 'Total com Imposto' deve ser numérico." ControlToValidate="tbMontanteMax"
            CssClass="error errorImage" Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="^[+-]?[0-9]{1,11}(?:\,[0-9]{1,2})?$"
            ValidationGroup="PesquisarFaturas">
            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

But, since they had the same ErrorMessage, I wanted to change this and put a CustomValidator to validate both TextBoxes at the same time. So I made this:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidatorTotalComImposto" CssClass="error" Display="Dynamic" runat="server"
            ErrorMessage="O campo 'Total com Imposto' deve ser numérico." OnServerValidate="ValidarTotalComImposto_ServerValidate" ValidationGroup="PesquisarFaturas" />
```

I'm trying to validate server side like this:

```
protected void ValidarTotalComImposto_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
        {
            bool TotalMinInvalido = false;
            bool TotalMaxInvalido = false;

            if (e.IsValid)
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbMontanteMin.Text) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbMontanteMax.Text))
                {
                    e.IsValid = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbMontanteMin.Text))
                    {
                        if (!IsDigitsOnly(tbMontanteMin.Text))
                        {
                            TotalMinInvalido = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbMontanteMax.Text))
                    {
                        if (!IsDigitsOnly(tbMontanteMax.Text))
                        {
                            TotalMaxInvalido = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (TotalMinInvalido || TotalMaxInvalido)
                    {
                        e.IsValid = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        e.IsValid = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I tested it. If I write on just one of the two textboxes (alfanumeric characters only input), the error appears. However, if I write alfanumeric characters on both textboxes, I wanted the error to appear (once), but I get this:

[Error in Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNh9K.png)

Thx for help!

Comment: why are you using server validate? is it because you have same error message on the regExp validator?

Comment: The two regExp validators were showing the same error message for two TextBoxes that were right next to each other. So I was asked to make only one message appear whether the error comes from one or both TextBoxes.

Comment: Could it be possible to control both RegExp, like for example. The error message would only appear if the other hasn't appeared yet (trough client side script or something)